# Cannot run Spring project in STS: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]When I create new Spring Starter Project in STS then run its. But it cannot run with Spring Boot App. I have same problem when I import a existing project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 5 more
```

Here is my maven config:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas why? Should I add another dependency or do I use a wrong version?

> Maven version: 3.5.0
>   Java version: 1.8
>   STS version: 3.9.3

Comment: run `mvn compile` and what you get?

Comment: Attach screenshot of your configuration class for spring boot.

Comment: This looks like a Spring Initializr project. What method are you using to get this code added to your Eclipse workspace?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, this is Spring Initialize project. But i have same problem with existing project

Comment: Spring Initializr projects are supported, and that's unlikely to be the problem. What I'm asking is how you're adding the project to the workspace.

Comment: @TKJohn I run command then building successfully. But it not work after that

Comment: @chrylis I import with existing maven project.

Comment: @Adya I have been added screenshot

Comment: Now please check the answer, I don't know why it has been downvote.

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run` try this command too

Comment: @Adya Thank you. But it is not working

Comment: @TKJohn Thank you. But it is not working.

Comment: So what is the output of `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: @TKJohn The result is build failure: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext. But i think the problem is in environment. Because, the another project (import from existing project) is not working too.

Comment: Check the file "spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar" of your Maven dependencies. Is this a valid Jar/Zip file? It should be about 1MB. And if so, treat it as `zip`file, check whether it contains "\org\springframework\context\ApplicationContextInitializer.class"

Comment: @TKJohn In maven repository for springframework context, it has spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar (1.858Kb) and spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar (1.106Kb). Both two libs contain "\org\springframework\context\ApplicationContextInitializer.class". In maven dependency is spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar.

Comment: can you please try the following: delete your local maven repository. Then build and run from command line - not from Eclipse. 1) mvn clean install 2) mvn spring-boot:run and tell what is the result of that. Thanks

Comment: @hovanessyan It is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AnhDuong awesome